# Application crashes when move from main view controller to another view controller, asks call a stack

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

```
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController
{

@IBOutlet weak var usernametext: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var emailtext: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordtext: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var retypepasswordtext: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.h
}

@IBAction func Signupbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let username = usernametext.text ;
    let useremail = emailtext.text ;
    let password = passwordtext.text ;
    let retypepassword = retypepasswordtext.text ;

    //alert message with confirmation
    func displayMyAlertMessage(UserMessage :String)
    {

        var myalert=UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:UserMessage,preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

      let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default , handler: nil)

        myalert.addAction(okAction)

        self.presentViewController(myalert, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }

    //check empty fields

    if(username.isEmpty || useremail.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || retypepassword.isEmpty)

    {
        //display alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("all fields are reqiured");
        return;

    }

    //password match 

    if(password != retypepassword)
    {
        //display alert message 

        displayMyAlertMessage("passwords do not match");

        return;
    }

    //store data

     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(username, forKey: "username")
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(useremail, forKey: "email")
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(password, forKey: "password")
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(retypepassword, forKey: "retypepassword")
    //alert msg

     }

}
```

error shown:-

```
2015-06-08 13:24:18.163 login excersice[3506:334174] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<login_excersice.SignUpViewController 0x7be6e4e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00293946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c6fa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00293561 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0071a10e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x00676138 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
    5   Foundation                          0x006760bd -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x006ab9a6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 386
    7   UIKit                               0x00ddc649 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c85724 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x001cd5dc -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 316
    10  UIKit                               0x00ddb10a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1775
    11  UIKit                               0x00bfd624 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 270
    12  UIKit                               0x00bfddbb -[UIViewController loadView] + 295
    13  UIKit                               0x00bfdfef -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    14  UIKit                               0x00bfe595 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x01271707 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 75
    16  UIKit                               0x00bd3a81 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 113
    17  UIKit                               0x00c0ba61 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2102
    18  UIKit                               0x00c0e5d2 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 345
    19  UIKit                               0x00c0e424 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 224
    20  UIKit                               0x00c130be -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 213
    21  UIKit                               0x00e4f3b5 -[UIStoryboardShowSegue perform] + 143
    22  UIKit                               0x010c3b49 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 217
    23  UIKit                               0x010c3bc5 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 116
    24  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c857cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    25  UIKit                               0x00aa823d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    26  UIKit                               0x00aa81cf -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    27  UIKit                               0x00bdbe86 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    28  UIKit                               0x00bdc2a3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    29  UIKit                               0x00bdb50d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    30  UIKit                               0x00af860a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    31  UIKit                               0x00af90e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    32  UIKit                               0x00abe549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    33  UIKit                               0x00ace37e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    34  UIKit                               0x00aa2b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x001b71df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x001acced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x001ac248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x001abbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x001ab9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x0402724f GSEventRunModal + 192
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x0402708c GSEventRun + 104
    42  UIKit                               0x00aa68b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    43  login excersice                     0x000a748e top_level_code + 78
    44  login excersice                     0x000a74cb main + 43
    45  libdyld.dylib                       0x023dcac9 start + 1
    46  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: check for `email` outlet in second controller

Answer (score -1):

Write below statement after storing data into `NSUserDefaults`

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`